# Synchronising client-side database on Android device with server-side database

Tags: android, database

I would like to build an Android application with a local SQLite database whose data can be send in XML format to a SQL server for data synchronisation.

Which are the best frameworks to accomplish this and which pitfalls and security issues do I have to watch out for? Are there any recommendable books that deal with this subject?